# Linux binary compatability

Tags: c++, linux, debian

I'm developing my C++ service application on debian 6.0 distribution, also I compile binary file on debian 6.0;
Could the binary work well on debian 5.0 distribution?

Comment: that completely depends on the used libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better compile them on Debian 5.0.

Linux kernel developers provide a backward compatibility, not a forward. But more probable are problems with basic libraries versions (such a glibc). See changes in them if you afraid crashes.

Comment: i find that most programs are quite agnostic of the linux kernel version, so this might not matter so much (but of course this depends on what the "service application" really does)

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely, but you can try. It might help to link as many libraries as humanly possible as "static", so that different versions on different systems don't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use a libstdc++/compiler version that is available on Debian-5.0.

e.g. when compiling using `g++-4.3` your binary will link against the corresponding `libstdc++6-4.3`, which should be available on Debian-5.0

note that the default c++-compiler on squeeze (Debian-6) is `g++-4.4`, which was **not** available on lenny.

so you might have to set your compiler/linker explicitly to `g++-4.5` (obviously after installing it :-))

```
$ ./configure CPP=cpp-4.5 CC=gcc-4.5 CXX=g++-4.5
$ make
```